# How to extract a pattern string from another using a REGEX in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, regex, t-sql

Is it possible in SQL Server to extract a string with a REGEX?

Something like `REGEXP_SUBSTR()` ?

I know with `PATINDEX()` I can use a REGEX to find the initial position, but I want it to extract directly the string that matches the pattern in the REGEX, does it exist in SQL Server?

Let's assume I have a message string like

```
@message = 
'- Tomorrow: 75 degrees (bla xyz)  
- Day 1: 78 degrees etc 3300 fx  
- Day 2: 76 degrees ppp 99  
- Day 3: 80 degrees xxx2 '
```

I need to extract in multiple string variables:

```
@tomorrow_temperature = '75'
@day_1_temperature '78'
@day_2_temperature '76'
@day_3_temperature '80'
```

How can I use REGEX to extract just the number associated to each day?
Is there any function that given a REGEX extract automatically the matching string

I tried using `PATINDEX()` but that of course extracts just the starting position of the string, it doesn't tell me how long it is and I don't want to use fixed amount of characters, just extract the whole string and from that extract the number of degrees

```
SELECT PATINDEX('%Day 1:%degrees', @message) Day_1;
```

---

I edited the example after Johns solution (my bad I made the example slightly different from reality), your solution applies perfectly to the previous example that I copy here in case anybody will need it in the future.

```
@message = 
'- Tomorrow: 75 degrees
 - Day 1: 78 degrees
 - Day 2: 76 degrees
 - Day 3: 80 degrees'
```

Thank you John!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just because it seemed like a fun diversion

**Example**

```
Declare @message varchar(max) = '- Tomorrow: 75 degrees (bla xyz)  
- Day 1: 78 degrees etc 3300 fx  
- Day 2: 76 degrees ppp 99  
- Day 3: 80 degrees xxx2 '

Declare @tomorrow_temperature varchar(10)
       ,@day_1_temperature varchar(10)
       ,@day_2_temperature varchar(10)
       ,@day_3_temperature varchar(10)

;with cte as (
Select Item  = JSON_VALUE(JS,'$[0]')
      ,Value = JSON_VALUE(JS,'$[1]')
 From  OpenJSON( '["'+replace(string_escape(@message,'json'),'degrees','","')+'"]' ) A
 Cross Apply (values ('["'+replace(string_escape(Value,'json'),':','","')+'"]') ) B(JS)
)
Select  @tomorrow_temperature = max(case when item like '%tomorrow%' then value end)
       ,@day_1_temperature    = max(case when item like '%day 1%' then value end)
       ,@day_2_temperature    = max(case when item like '%day 2%' then value end)
       ,@day_3_temperature    = max(case when item like '%day 3%' then value end)
 From  cte
```

**Straight Text way**

```
Declare @message varchar(max) = '- Tomorrow: 75 degrees (bla xyz)  
- Day 1: 78 degrees etc 3300 fx  
- Day 2: 76 degrees ppp 99  
- Day 3: 80 degrees xxx2 '

Declare @tomorrow_temperature varchar(10) = trim(substring(@message,charindex('Tomorrow',@message)+10,3))
       ,@day_1_temperature    varchar(10) = trim(substring(@message,charindex('Day 1'   ,@message)+7 ,3))
       ,@day_2_temperature    varchar(10) = trim(substring(@message,charindex('Day 2'   ,@message)+7 ,3))
       ,@day_3_temperature    varchar(10) = trim(substring(@message,charindex('Day 3'   ,@message)+7 ,3))

Select  @tomorrow_temperature
       ,@day_1_temperature
       ,@day_2_temperature
       ,@day_3_temperature
```

Comment: Different from what I was expecting, but great solution! Thank you very much John, you are a bomb (:

Comment: @HarryKane As you have figured out by now, SQL Server does not support REGEX .   Seems like a missed opportunity

Comment: I really have no words, I saw we can use REGEX in the WHERE clause but not a function to extract substrings using REGEX? For real it doesn't exists? 
Seems too lame to be true

You gave me an incredible solution to be honest, but let me take advantage one second more of your skills (if you have 5 more minutes otherwise thanks anyway).. 
how would you have extracted it singularly using PATINDEX and SUBSTRING using each single variable assignment?

Comment: Shut, I think I made a wrong example in the @message source tho.. 
Correct is:

`@message = 
'- Tomorrow: 75 degrees (bla xyz)
 - Day 1: 78 degrees etc 3300 fx
 - Day 2: 76 degrees ppp 99
 - Day 3: 80 degrees xxx2 '`

Comment: @HarryKane Take a peek at https://dbfiddle.uk/ckln48Qc ..   Note the like '% ... %' in the final query

Comment: @HarryKane Just to be clear, it was really not REGEX in the WHERE.   It was more of a limited pattern match

Comment: @HarryKane  See updated anwser.  I added a a straight text method

Comment: Still I am shocked you had to use all that witchcraft and MSSQL doesn't support string extraction by REGEX.. #_# 
Thanks again John! You da beast!